# Swift Firebase Cloud Messaging - Sending upstream messages in the background

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I wasn't able to find anything on this topic in the documentation, so I thought I'd as it here.

The FCM documentation states that:

> When your app goes into the background, disconnect from FCM.

But no where does it say why.

What I want to do is send an FCM upstream message from the device when a user interacts with a push notification (could be local or remote).

So I have two questions:

1. Why does Firebase recommend we disconnect from FCM when the app is sent to the background?
2. Can I send an upstream message while the app is killed, suspended, or in the background?

This type of feature, where the user interacts with a notification, and an immediate server response, is going to be a major part of my app, and I need to know if this is possible with Firebase, otherwise I need to start looking for another solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I wasn't able to find an answer online, I decided to implement my use case and observe the behaviour. I found a few things:

- You can't rely on background execution in iOS, such as keeping an FCM connection. The system can and will kill your app in low memory states.
- Trying to connect to FCM in the background will not work. Any messages sent in the background will be queued for when the app is next opened.
- Even if your background code is guaranteed to run, such as during a notification action, FCM cannot connect.

Given my findings, the answers to my questions are:

1. Because you can't rely on background execution on iOS (see first bullet above).
2. No, the messages are queued for when the app is next opened and a valid FCM connection is made.